# Strange output using array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I am working on one of the programs using arrays.
What I want is to..add the elements of the char array and give the output.
Here's the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
char number[8];
int in , i = 0 , square = 0;
cin>>number;
while(1){
    if(i != strlen(number)){
    square = (number[i]) + square;
    cout<<square<<"\n";

    }
    else{
        break;
    }
    i++;
}
cout<<square - 48*(strlen(number));
return 0;
}
```

the strange thing is that the output is 48 x (the number of digits of input) more than the original input, that is why I have subtracted that part from the output.
Why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number[i]` is a character, but you are treating it as if it was an integer. `'0'` (a character) does not equal `0` (an integer), `'1'` does not equal `1` etc. The simple way to convert a decimal digit character to an integer is to subtract `'0'` from it. Like this

```
square = (number[i] - '0') + square;
```

`'0' - '0'` does equal `0`, `'1' - '0'` does equal `1`, etc.

Comment: I tried int(number[i]) for converting that didn't work.
Never knew about the way you suggested., it worked.